# Encode each comma separated value in Pandas

Tags: pandas, categorical-data, python-3.x, one-hot-encoding, categorical-encoding

I have a dataset

```
Inp1    Inp2        Inp3               Output
A,B,C   AI,UI,JI    Apple,Bat,Dog      Animals
L,M,N   LI,DO,LI    Lawn, Moon, Noon   Noun
X,Y     AI,UI       Yemen,Zombie       Extras
```

For these values, I need to apply a ML algorithm. Hence need an encoding technique.
Tried a Label encoding technique, it encodes the entire cell to an `int` for eg.

```
Inp1    Inp2    Inp3    Output
5       4       8       0
```

But I need a separate encoding for each value in a cell. How should I go about it.

```
Inp1     Inp2    Inp3      Output
7,44,87  4,65,2  47,36,20  45
```

Integers are random here.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I don't use pandas so I can't help with the details, but apparently your features are lists of categorical variables. The standard way would be to one-hot encode all these lists, i.e. replace each column with as many boolean features as there are possible values. You should probably discard the least frequent values, especially of the number is high.

Comment: One-hot encode increases the number of columns, which is not desirable as there would be an issue of Dimensionality.

Comment: Indeed, but if you keep encoding these lists as a single variable the ML model will certainly be unable to learn anything at all. The design of the features should be made to properly represent the semantic of the data and help the model find the relevant patterns.

Comment: Yes, true. Thanks a lot. I am fairly new to this domain so trying to learn more. It would be great if you suggest any reference to go about this.

Comment: This question would get better answers in Stackoverflow which is for programming questions.